# How to embed Youtube live chat whitin github pages

Tags: html, iframe, github-pages, youtube-iframe-api

I was trying using embed iframe but it actually doesn't work, maybe it is a problem with github pages because it is not in a custom domain.

```
<iframe width=”350px” height=”500px” src=”https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=yourvideoid&embed_domain=yourdomainnamegoeshere.com” ></iframe>
```

In domain I put these options:

- https://lucho19jose.github.io/
- lucho19jose.github.io
- [www.lucho19jose.github.io](http://www.lucho19jose.github.io)

It throw 404 error

Comment: Have you swapped the video id placeholder?

Comment: I am just following the tutorial https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en#zippy=%2Cembed-live-chat